# How to change the values in textbox using capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

For example the text box is having the value 10
I need to change the value to 20

while I am using the below Capybara command,

> > fill_in "#{ID}", :with => "20"

the value is not getting changed ... instead its appended as 1020.

Give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to use javascript to do this. I wrote a separate step to clear the field before changing the value.

```
page.execute_script("$('#{field_id}').val('');")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
 fill_in "ID", :with => "20"
```

Comment: fill_in "ID", :with => "20"
and
fill_in "#{ID}", :with => "20"

both are same ... In my case ID is a variable and I am storing the id of the text box into the variable ID

In both the cases output is same. 

And any other solution to achieve this ??

Comment: have a look at this thread - looks like someone else had the same issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/LZ6eu0kuRY0/PLrLzXDJSMEJ